# How to call method when AVAudioPlayer reaches a certain playback time?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to perform an action when the playback reaches a certain time. I can't find any delegate methods or examples of how to do this. How can I call a method when the playback reaches a certain point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should help you [addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388027-addboundarytimeobserverfortimes)

> Requests the invocation of a block when specified times are traversed
>   during normal playback.

**Objective C:**

```
- (id)addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)times 
                                queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue 
                           usingBlock:(void (^)(void))block;
```

**Swift:**

```
func addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes times: [NSValue], 
                       queue: DispatchQueue?, 
                       using block: @escaping () -> Void) -> Any
```

**Usage:**

```
_ = self.player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: times, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: {
    [weak self] time in
    // Your code goes here
})
```

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: This method isn't on `AVAudioPlayer` - you have to switch to using `AVPlayer` instead if you want to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on some more details.

You can `addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes:queue:using:)` for a certain time or use `addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval:queue:using:)` for periodic intervals.

```
 // for specific time
func addTimeObserver() {
    var times = [NSValue]()

    var currentTime = kCMTimeZero // make your time here

        times.append(NSValue(time:currentTime))

    // Queue on which to invoke the callback
    let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main

    // Add time observer
    timeObserverToken =
        player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: times, queue: mainQueue) {
            [weak self] time in
            // Update UI
    }
}
```

To fire every half second during normal playback

```
func addPeriodicTimeObserver() {
// Invoke callback every half second
let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.5,
                      preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))

let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main

timeObserverToken =
    player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: mainQueue) {
        [weak self] time in
        // update UI
}}
```

Comment: This is only works for AVPlayer.  This is not available to AVAudioPlayer as the OP had requested.